# Nginx proxy conf for minecraft not working

Tags: nginx, centos, minecraft

Hi I am trying to get a nginx conf working with minecraft.

I created several subdomains (A-records) and I want to use only the subdomains (without port).
Therefore I installed nginx (stable release) on CentOS 7.
Added portforward in my router on 25565 to this VM (fixed IP) and added 25565 (tcp, permanent) to the firewall. Testing nginx with default ip (port 80) => Welcome to nginx....
Testing port 25565 (with minecraft) also works.

Left nginx.conf and default.conf intact (no changes) and added my minecraft.conf in /etc/nginx/conf.d/
Minecraft uses tcp protocol (I asume this is supported by nginx) and listens default to 25565 that's why I run my instances on 25566 and 25567

As far as I understood main directives like http(s), stream etc. should be declared in nginx.conf
It's not posible to declare a stream in the minecraft.conf (in ./conf.d/)
Also not possible to proxy_pass to the upstream (directive proxy_pass not allowed here)
(I can use location / { http://..} but that's not tcp)

What do I miss to make it work as I want to use a proxy (Network Solutions does not allow SRV records for subdomains)

my minecraft.conf:

```
upstream mcserver1 {
    server 192.168.1.14:25566;
}
upstream mcserver2 {
    server 192.168.1.14:25567;
}
server {
    listen 25565;
    server_name camelot.xyz.net;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mcs1.access;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mcs1.error;
    proxy_pass mcserver1;
}
server {
    listen 25565;
    server_name cityworld.xyz.net;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mcs2.access;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mcs2.error;
    proxy_pass mcserver2;
}
```

In the default error.log I find
2021/04/11 21:37:12 [notice] 5525#5525: signal process started
2021/04/11 21:37:12 [emerg] 2325#2325: bind() to 0.0.0.0:25565 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/04/11 21:37:12 [emerg] 2325#2325: still could not bind()